# Multiple accordions (first open as default + close automatically when another is opened)

Tags: html, css, accordion

I am trying to make the first accordion open as default, and make others close automatically when another is opened.

HTML

```
<div class="product__accordion accordion" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
  <details>
    <summary>
      <div class="summary__title">
        {% render 'icon-accordion', icon: block.settings.icon %}
        <h2 class="h4 accordion__title">
          {{ block.settings.heading | default: block.settings.page.title }}
        </h2>
      </div>
      {% render 'icon-caret' %}
    </summary>
    <div class="accordion__content rte">
      {{ block.settings.content }}
      {{ block.settings.page.content }}
    </div>
  </details>
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
.accordion summary {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
}

.accordion .summary__title {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.accordion + .accordion {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: none;
}

.accordion {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 0.1rem solid rgba(var(--color-foreground), 0.08);
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid rgba(var(--color-foreground), 0.08);
}

.accordion__title {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: calc(100% - 6rem);
  min-height: 1.6rem;
  margin: 0;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.accordion .icon-accordion {
  align-self: center;
  min-width: 1.6rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  fill: rgb(var(--color-foreground));
}

.accordion details[open] > summary .icon-caret {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion__content {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.accordion__content img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

I have noticed that if I turn `<details>` into `<details open>` every accordion is open as default but I only want the first one...
Also want when one is opened the other closes automatically.

The browser inspect goes like this:

[accordion.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGsu6.jpg)

Can you help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <style>
    .accordion-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #0079c1;
  border-top: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

.accordion-container .article-title {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.625em 0.625em 0.625em 2em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-container .article-title:hover,
.accordion-container .article-title:active,
.accordion-container .content-entry.open .article-title {
  background-color: #00aaa7;
  color: white;
}

.accordion-container .article-title:hover i:before,
.accordion-container .article-title:hover i:active,
.accordion-container .content-entry.open i {
  color: white;
}

.article-title{
  position: relative;
}

.article-title:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 38%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-top: solid 2px #fff;
  border-right: solid 2px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.article-title.open:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 45%;
}

.accordion-content {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 2.3125em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.accordion-content.open{

display:block;
}

/* CSS for CodePen */
.accordion-container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 1.875em auto;
}
    </style>
    <title>Alicja Wilińska - usługi informatyczne</title>
  </head>
  <body>
            <div id="accordion" class="accordion-container">
  <h4 class="article-title open">Accordion Title 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content open">
    <p>Accordion content 1</p>
  </div><!--/.accordion-content-->

  <h4 class="article-title">Accordion Title 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Accordion content 2</p>
  </div><!--/.accordion-content-->

  <h4 class="article-title">Accordion Title 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Accordion content 3</p>
  </div><!--/.accordion-content-->

  <h4 class="article-title">Accordion Title 4</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Accordion content 4</p>
  </div><!--/.accordion-content-->

</div><!--/#accordion-->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.article-title').on('click', function () {
            $('.open').removeClass('open');
            $(this).next('.accordion-content').toggleClass('open');
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope U got results.

Comment: Thank you for the share @sunnyparsana , but I think that in this case the problem is that they are not just tabs, are single accordions, can you take a look to the EDIT I did, I added not both HTML and CSS. Thank you